# RequiredFieldValidator - So if Javascript is disabled the whole .NET controls are avoided?

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm using .NET recently, and I check some fields.

I know that the check is client-side (javascript) and on server-side with :

```
Page.Validate();

if (!Page.IsValid)
{
}
```

But if the javascript is disabled all of them are not checked (in fact the javascript return false when I try to do the request to the server.

So, is this a limitation of .NET or there are other way to do these check without JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, using `Page.IsValid` will only return correct value if javascript is enabled / supported in the browser. So, good web programming practice is to run same validations again at server side regardless of client side validation consideration. Because client side javascript can be altered easily in browser to bypass that the validations.

That will ensure you are accepting correct values.

Comment: To extend you answer: The client side validation is provided as a convenience for the user - The server side validation is used to ensure the data is correct. Their purpose is completely different and thus they shouldn't be confused.

Comment: Yeah, but that's my question : without javascript I can't use those controls?

Comment: @markzzz: Without Javascript, you can't use any Control that requires Javascript. Should be a no-brainer :-)

Comment: That's right, without javascript you will not be able to use any of the validation controls in asp.net. In fact, in that case, many other controls also doesn't work, example is LinkButton control.